# MS SQL 2017 парсинг JSON c вычисляемым/изменяемым путём в JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возможно ли сделать путь парсинга в JSON_VALUE изменяемым? Подскажите работающий вариант
Моя попытка была такой:

```
declare @a varchar(100);
declare @b varchar(100);
set @b = 3;
set @a = '$.Results."'+cast(@b as varchar)+'".test';
select JSON_VALUE ([JSON], @a) as 'test' from mytable
```

В данном варианте @a = $.Results."3".test, а должен быть в кавычках '$.Results."3".test'

Comment: Да запросто. Путь - обычный строковый литерал, и может легко собираться строкковыми операторами и фнукциями.

Comment: @Akina concat не работает, есть другой вариант?

Comment: Я. конечно, милль пардон, но вы за сообщениями об ошибках что, принципиально не смотрите?

Comment: @Akina Я понимаю что путь должен быть строковым литералом, но не понимаю как туда динамически вписывать изменения, поэтому и задал вопрос, если у Вас есть решение, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `set @a = '$.Results."' + CAST(@b AS VARCHAR) + '".test';`

Comment: @Akina MS SQL выдаёт туже ошибку: "The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal."
Я думаю проблема в том что @a  = $.Results."3".test а должен быть '$.Results."3".test' не пойму как этого добиться.

Comment: Делайте fiddle, воспроизводящий проблему - будем посмотреть.